# I am unable to import opencv i.e. cv2 in raspberry pi zero w 2 python program

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

```
# This is code which makes use of cv2
import os
from picamera.array import PiRGBArray
from picamera import PiCamera
import time
import numpy as np
import pytesseract
import cv2

print(cv2.__version__)
```

Comment: And what happens when you do that?

Comment: Did you installed all prerequisites `sudo apt-get install build-essential cmake pkg-config libjpeg-dev libtiff5-dev libjasper-dev libpng-dev libavcodec-dev libavformat-dev libswscale-dev libv4l-dev libxvidcore-dev libx264-dev libfontconfig1-dev libcairo2-dev libgdk-pixbuf2.0-dev libpango1.0-dev libgtk2.0-dev libgtk-3-dev libatlas-base-dev gfortran libhdf5-dev libhdf5-serial-dev libhdf5-103 python3-pyqt5 python3-dev -y` ? Are you sure you installed opencv from pip correctly? Try `pip list`. Also you can try `sudo apt-get install python-opencv` instead of pip

Comment: Hi thanks Tim. It appears I was using the sudo which was accessing root where as I have installed the opencv in certain user directory.